# How to use React.useContext(AuthContext) inside a class component to trigger a condition set in index.js file

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-context

My project file code snippets are as follows
Index.js

```
import { AuthContext } from './components/context';
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
export default function App() {

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [userFound, setUserFound] = useState(false);
   
  
  const authContext=React.useMemo(()=>({     
    skipOn:async() =>{      
     setSkip(true);
    
    },
    skipOff:async()=>{
      setSkip(false);
    }
  }),[])

 
  return (


    <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
    <NavigationContainer >
      { (userFound || skip) ? (<Drawer.Navigator
        drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props} />}
        headerMode='none'
        screenOptions={{
          header: () => (null)
        }}>
        <Drawer.Screen name="HomeDrawer" component={HomeStackScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="OfferDrawer" component={OfferStackScreen} />

      </Drawer.Navigator>) : <LoginStackScreen/>}

    </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthContext.Provider>

  );
}
```

when user tries to login , if he chooses to skip the process, he will trigger the skipOn() method. skipOff() would land the user back to login screen. I want to access skipOff in a HomeStackScreen component on button press .Below is the code snippet. How to access the authcontext inside class component

```
class CardItemDetails extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      isFavorite: false,
      item: { isLoading: true, errMess: null, item: null, discount: null }
    }
  }
  orderNowHandler = () => {
    if (currentuser is authenticated) {
      
           navigate to another screen
    }
    else {
      trigger skipOff() and land on login page
  }
```

I am always getting invalid hooks call exception while trying to invoke skipOff(). What is the correct way of invoking/implementing this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

To consume a context inside *class* component, you can assign a [`contextType`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype) to read the current context. Using `contextType` lets you consume the nearest current value of that Context type using `this.context`. You can reference this in any of the lifecycle methods including the render function.

So, you can write:

```
import { AuthContext } from './components/context';

class CardItemDetails extends Component {
  static contextType = AuthContext // assign static contextType
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { ...code here... }
  }

  orderNowHandler = (e) => {
    if (writeYourConditionHere) {
      this.context.skipOn() // consume the context values or functions
    } else {
      this.context.skipOff()
    }
  }
```

Also, see the hook [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) which lets you consume context values in *function* components.

*PS:* You cannot use `React.useContext(AuthContext)` inside a class component because [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) (`useContext` here) can only be used in a function component.